# XeLaTeX: Shift baseline of Tibetan font

Tags: fonts, xetex, polyglossia

I had a look at different approaches discussed on SO, but they either don't apply to the Tibetan font (e.g. only CJK fonts) or they lower the whole line (not just the part inside the curly braces) or they involve a block which prevents automatic line breaks from working (like `\raisebox`).

Any idea how I can lower the baseline of the Tibetan font (BabelStrone Tibetan) to make it align with the English text around it?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{tibetan}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily{\tibetanfont}[Scale=1.415]{BabelStone Tibetan}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}
the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’\\
\end{document}
```

I want to make it look like in the second line in the image below where I'm using a different Tibetan font that has better vertical alignment.

[image: First line: BabelStrone Tiebetan. Second line: DDC Uchen]

Comment: Will this help? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282342/possible-to-vertically-shift-baseline-without-using-a-box

Comment: Apparently the font has peculiar ideas about the baseline of Tibetan glyphs; if I use another font I have on my machine I get [this output (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VyVdl.png)

Comment: @DavidPurton I tried patching `\tibetanfont` with the xelatex version of that command, which is `\special{pdf:literal 1 0 0 1 0 -2 cm}`, but it shifts the rest of the line as well, even if I try to shift back at the end of the patch.

Comment: This is the patch I'm using:

    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \pretocmd{\tibetanfont}{\special{pdf:literal 1 0 0 1 0 -2 cm}}{}{}
    \apptocmd{\tibetanfont}{\special{pdf:literal 1 0 0 1 0 2 cm}}{}{}

Comment: etoolbox is not clever enough to patch the `\texttibetan` macro. But I think `xpatch` can do it. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Hmm, which font is that? @egreg

Comment: Side remark: "variant=british" is buggy: https://github.com/reutenauer/polyglossia/issues/167#issuecomment-303541344

Comment: Thanks @UlrikeFischer! I don't think I've run into any noticeable problems with it so far but I'll keep it in mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282342/possible-to-vertically-shift-baseline-without-using-a-box), you can adjust the baseline with a PDF special.

Update to allow for difference font sizes.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}
\setotherlanguage{tibetan}
\setmainfont{Charis SIL}
\newfontfamily{\tibetanfont}[Scale=1.415]{BabelStone Tibetan}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\dim_new:N \g__naoki_offset_dim
\cs_new:Nn \__naoki_calc_offset:
  {
    \dim_set:Nn \g__naoki_offset_dim { 1 ex * \dim_ratio:nn { 2 pt } { 5 pt } }
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \dropbaseline { }
  {
    \__naoki_calc_offset:
    \special{pdf:literal~1~0~0~1~0~-\dim_to_decimal:n { \g__naoki_offset_dim }~cm}
  }
\NewDocumentCommand \raisebaseline { }
  {
    \__naoki_calc_offset:
    \special{pdf:literal~1~0~0~1~0~\dim_to_decimal:n { \g__naoki_offset_dim }~cm}
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpretocmd{\texttibetan}{\dropbaseline}{}{}
\xapptocmd{\texttibetan}{\raisebaseline}{}{}

\newlength{\tempdima}
\begin{document}
English {\tibetanfont\dropbaseline རྫོང་\raisebaseline} English

\Huge the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’

\huge the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’

\LARGE the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’

\Large the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’

\large the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’

\normalsize the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’

\small the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’

\footnotesize the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’

\scriptsize the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’

\tiny the \texttibetan{རྫོང་} \textbf{dzong} ‘fortress’
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @DavidPurton! Your solution does the job perfectly for `\texttibetan`. But I would also need `\tibetanfont` to lower the baseline. Any idea how I can do that?

Comment: @NoakiPeter, you would need to manually add the PDF special (via a macro if you like) before and after your text for it to be reliable I think.

Comment: It won't work correctly with other font sizes.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, is that better?

Comment: Yes ;-). (I would probably change the special with a driver dependent command so that it works also with luatex.). But the real fix is naturally to correct the font.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer, luatex can be left as an exercise for the reader ;)