# Raise baseline for English in XeLaTeX in a bilingual document

Tags: fonts, xetex, baseline

Please see the MWE given below.

```
\documentclass{article}

% For bilingual document
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{fontspec}

% Bangla
\setmainlanguage[numerals=Devanagari]{bengali}
\newfontfamily\bengalifont[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Kalpurush}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontbf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Kalpurush}
\newfontfamily\bengalifonttt[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Kalpurush}
\newfontfamily\bengalifontsf[Script=Bengali,AutoFakeBold=4.0,AutoFakeSlant=0.4]{Kalpurush}

\setotherlanguage{english}
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

% Times New Roman used
\newfontfamily\englishfont[Mapping=tex-text, Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

বাংলা-\textenglish{-Bangla}

বেস লাইনে মিল নেই \textenglish{The baselines do not match}

\end{document}
```

In the output, as we can see, the baselines do not match for Bengali and English. This is clearly evidenced by the two dashes placed side-by-side. The overall effect looks awkward and makes the document ugly.

[image]

The easiest hack I can think of is to raise the baseline for the English text.

(I tried adopting [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457727/14103). Unfortunately, this did not work. I don't know why.
I don't have enough knowledge of LaTeX3 to debug.)

The non-English font used can be found [here](https://www.omicronlab.com/download/fonts/kalpurush.ttf).

Comment: Maybe scaling down the Bangla font a bit?

Comment: @egreg Indeed, that turned out to be a simple but effective solution. Though I had to try different values for matching the dashes.