# \hrulefill with vertical alignment of the line as in dashes

Tags: vertical-alignment, rules, fill

`\hrulefill` vertically aligns the line at the bottom of the text.
There is also `\xrfill` in the package `xhfill` which raises the line, but it is raised too much for my esthetics.

What I'm looking for is a command working similarly to `\hrulefill`, but such that the filler line is like a stretched em-dash, so the vertical alignment is the same as for an em-dash.

**EDIT**

As a clarification: I don't want to have to guess the thickness nor the amount the line is raised over the baseline. I want a command which produces a stretched em-dashed, independently of the current font size etc.

Comment: See: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282342/possible-to-vertically-shift-baseline-without-using-a-box In xelatex, I tried this `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}
x \special{pdf:literal 1 0 0 1 0 2 cm} \hrulefill \special{pdf:literal 1 0 0 1 0 -2 cm} x

x -- x\end{document}`

Comment: @Cicada Thank you. This looks like a pretty technical approach to me. I'm not using xelatex. Shouldn't there be a smoother way to accomplish this in pdflatex?

Comment: pdftex uses `\pdfliteral`, per the linked question. You can define a macro to do the technical bit and just call the macro (use a short name to save typing). Or do you want to do it some other way? Draw a `\rule` and use `\raisebox`, for example.

Comment: @Cicada thank you. Would you mind making a regular answer out of your ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
\def\myrulefillat{.65ex}
\def\myrulefill{\leaders \hrule height\myrulefillat 
                                depth-\dimexpr \myrulefillat-.3pt\relax \hfil}

test:

\hbox to3cm{a --\myrulefill -- b}
```

The height of this rule is given by `\myrulefillat` macro and the thickness is .3pt. You can set another values.

Answer (score 0):

Since the rule is drawn in relation to the baseline, raising the baseline will raise the rule.

And since the command syntax is long and very low-level, storing all the technicality in a macro with a short name is useful and saves typing.

Using this answer (David Carlisle + a comment by flow), raising the baseline without using boxes or lua, [Possible to vertically shift baseline without using a box?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282342/possible-to-vertically-shift-baseline-without-using-a-box)

gives:

`\special` in xelatex

[image: xelatex]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\hrf{\special{pdf:literal 1 0 0 1 0 2 cm}\hrulefill\special{pdf:literal 1 0 0 1 0 -2 cm}}

\begin{document}
\textbackslash special with xelatex

no change x\hrulefill x

raised x\special{pdf:literal 1 0 0 1 0 2 cm}\hrulefill \special{pdf:literal 1 0 0 1 0 -2 cm}x

macro x\hrf x


\end{document}
```

or `\pdfliteral` in pdflatex

[image: pdflatex]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\hrfp{\pdfliteral{ 1 0  0 1 0 2 cm}\hrulefill\pdfliteral{ 1 0  0 1 0 -2 cm}}

\begin{document}
\textbackslash pdfliteral with pdflatex

no change x\hrulefill x

raised x\pdfliteral{ 1 0  0 1 0 2 cm}\hrulefill\pdfliteral{ 1 0  0 1 0 -2 cm}x

macro x\hrfp x


\end{document}
```